# Register Broadcast Receiver from outside of onStartCommand in a Service

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

I am using Observer Pattern to update my Service for new receivers to register. Service class is the Observer and is notified when it has to register for new receiver.

```
public class ServiceAlpha extends Service implements Observer {

private Map<BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter> localReceivers = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand:  service started");
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}


@Override
public void onReceiverAdded() {

    MapDifference<BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter> diff = Maps.difference(ReceiversList.receivers, localReceivers);

    for (Map.Entry<BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter> entry : diff.entriesOnlyOnLeft().entrySet()) {
        BroadcastReceiver key = entry.getKey();
        IntentFilter value = entry.getValue();

        Log.i(TAG, "onReceiverAdded: key: " + key + " value: " + value + " context: " + this);
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(key, value);  //registering the receiver
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onReceiverAdded: added something on the list");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

When a new item is added to the HashMap, onReceiverAdded is called and receiver is registered. But I keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`. I have tried replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `this` but still get similar error.

However, there was no problem when I registered for receiver in `onStartCommand` method.

The debug log before the receiver gives this output:

`onReceiverAdded: key: io.rudevdr.simpleservice.receivers.ChargingReceiver@168bb5f value: android.content.IntentFilter@d28e9ac context: io.rudevdr.simpleservice.services.ServiceAlpha@8a61675`.

I don't get why I get NullPointerException when all three values are not null.

Any help/comment is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: code? how you are interacting with service class ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)